# Firebase permission-denied error after changing rule in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

this is my updated rule for firebase database. after updating this rule with static uid now error is showing that Firebase permission-denied.

```
"rules": {
    ".read" : "auth !== null && auth.uid=='xxxxstatic_idxxxx'",
    ".write" : true
}
```

this is my configuration code, now what changed should I do in code so that I will get permission to read from database.

```
const config = {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    databaseURL: "https://db_name.firebaseio.com/",
    storageBucket: "db_name.appspot.com",
    authDomain: "db_name.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own. Please edit your question to include the minimum code that generates this error message.

Comment: that is the question, what is the code in JavaScript that will allow me to access the data from database.

Comment: Your titles says you're getting a `Firebase permission-denied error after changing rule in firebase`, which I assume you weren't expecting. Please show the code that throws that error unexpectedly.

Comment: I have not added any related code to connect with firebase after this change in rule. that is why this error is there. so I am asking for that code or any function of JavaScript that will connect to firebase database..

Comment: Where or how is your app authenticating to Firebase? Can you include that code? Also, what is the purpose of `auth.uid=='xxxxstatic_idxxxx'",` - are you attempting to limit access to just the authenticated user or something else? e.g. hard-coded uid's may not be a good long term situation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#realtime-database) you should match this pattern:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($userId)
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I understand you want to grant permission only to one specific user, then `$userId` should be replaced with `xxxxstatic_idxxxx`

Comment: what about config code? Need to pass this uid from config file then only it will match and get the permission to read. how to pass it from config file?